# <TOAD for Oracle> How to use F5 for this set of statements?

Tags: sql, oracle, toad

This are my statements

---

```
SELECT BATCH_MANAGE.BATCH_SEQ_NUM.NEXTVAL
FROM QUEUE;

INSERT INTO batch_manage.wrk_user
(batch_sequence_number, source_number, status, locale_sid_key, timezone_sid_key, email_encoding_key, language_locale_key)

VALUES (:batch_id, :badge, :status, :location, :timezone, :email_encoding, :language);

SELECT *
FROM batch_manage.wrk_user;
```

---

Basically if I use F9, i can run these separately but I want to modify it so that with a hit of F5, it will run all of these and finally produce the answer at the last select

All the INSERT (except batch_id), user must entered them at the beginning.
I tried declaring a variable but it will not store the `BATCH_MANAGE.BATCH_SEQ_NUM.NEXTVAL` into it.

This is my first time using TOAD or even SQL

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps selecting the whole script would work: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> then <kbd>F5</kbd>

Unless, of course, auto-commit is turned off.

Comment: nope, it didn't work because it is not able to detect the batch_id

Comment: Sorry, bro... just been too long since TOAD for me.